# Confused about ということ along with なのだ

Tags: grammar, meaning, nuances, dictionary

I was a little confused about the meaning of "ということなのです" in this sentence:

> 皆さん同じようにユーチューブスタジオの過去の動画見ても一覧見ても全部収益化のマークが外れてるって言うことなんだよね

I have found this definition in a Japanese dictionary:

> と‐いうこと◦だ〔‐いふことだ〕【と言うことだ】
> ［連語］
> ２ 話し手が他者の心を推測して、断定的に述べる意を表す。「結局われわれは信用されていない—◦だ」

But like I said, I still don't know the exact meaning. Is it like "to conclude a point"? Or "to affirm something"?

Comment: Related https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/76452/45489

Answer (score 1):

I think the sentence is a little bit weird or childish since there's no punctuation and the word choice is too casual. I don't think this sentence is written by a Japanese who has enough educational background.
Aside from that, in this sentence "っていうことなんだよね。"can be divided into "っていうことなんだ"+"よね”.
As you have mentioned "っていうことなんだ" is often used when someone conclude or rephrase what s/he has said. For example, " 彼女はカレーとキムチが好きなんだ。つまり辛い物が大好きっていうことなんだ。".
And the "よね" is used when someone wants to seek empathy for what s/he has said.